# How to add a scrolling chat button with popups

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently using https://getbutton.io/. But problem is they have very slow css and JavaScript. I want to create my own scrolling button like this for Facebook and WhatsApp. Please help me to code

https://static.getbutton.io/css/whatshelp-font.css

https://static.getbutton.io/widget-send-button/js/widget/desktop.js

https://static.getbutton.io/widget-send-button/css/style.css

https://static.getbutton.io/widget-send-button/js/init.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            facebook: "1769615853297972", // Facebook page ID
            whatsapp: "+9203038518000", // WhatsApp number
            call_to_action: "Message us", // Call to action
            button_color: "#FF6550", // Color of button
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
            order: "facebook,whatsapp", // Order of buttons
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "getbutton.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
<!-- /WhatsHelp.io widget -->

Please help me to make my own code so I did'nt need to use getbutton js and css files and I can host on my own server.
```

Comment: What is a scrolling button?

Comment: exactly, whats a scrolling button and are you sure about the links you added in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            facebook: "1769615853297972", // Facebook page ID
            whatsapp: "+9203038518000", // WhatsApp number
            call_to_action: "Message us", // Call to action
            button_color: "#FF6550", // Color of button
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
            order: "facebook,whatsapp", // Order of buttons
        };
                 var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.